# TYPO3 How to make submenu on using my tree structure?

Tags: typo3, submenu, fluid-layout, typo3-6.1.x

How to make submenu on using my tree structure

This is my tree structure

```
 - Home
 - About Us
 - Example

  - List item
  - List item
  - List item
```

And This is my Typoscript

```
lib.content_menu = COA
lib.content_menu {
    10 = HMENU
   10 {
        wrap = <div class="menu_left menu_ul">|</div>
        entryLevel = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            wrap = <div class="menu_1"><ul>|</ul></div>
           target = _top
            NO {
   wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
    }
     ACT < .NO
 ACT = 1
 CUR < .NO
CUR = 1
 CUR {
  allWrap = <div class="menu_act">|</div>
}}
```

how to make the submenu on example page using the above structure?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

In TMENU create a new level. Copy level 1 and fix the html: 2 < .1.

Comment: please explain it with example